# Edit Page Layout Assignment Privilege

Tags: page-layout, privileges

One of my users has Customize application privilege but he is not able to assign himself a different layout for a standard object. What privilege does he need?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they need the “Manage Profiles and Permission Sets” permission as well.  See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_record_types.htm&type=0